# how to create new arrays in for loop with python 3?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to create some new arrays using for loop in python, is it possible?
Here is the problem:
I have an array with some numbers that user input like this :

```
number_of_digits = 20
digits = [0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,5,2,3]
```

so I removed the numbers that were bigger that 2 and in this sample the result will be like this:

```
digits = [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

I need to create some new arrays with 3 digits!
so my question is how to create new arrays when I do not know the number of them when coding! (I think to use a for loop to create them for me depends on the length of digits array, but as I tried it is no possible !
can you help me please?

Comment: Can you specify your exact input and output ?

Comment: It's not quite clear what the question is.

Comment: @utsavan I get the digits from user input, I know how to filter the numbers lower than 2 but my question is how to create the new lists( arrays) using python when I do not know how many list I out to creat!

Comment: @ArianKhademzadeh Can you tell on what criteria you are going create new list ?

Comment: @utsavan I want to the loop create some lists that contain 3 digits, every number that extracted from digits list must be use just in one new list and can not use in several lists, for example: if digits list is : [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2] so the loop return user like this:
list_1 : [0, 1, 0]
list_2 : [1, 2, 2]
list_3 : [2, 1, 2]
and the remaining [1,2] will not use to create another list .

Answer (score 0):

here you got the list:

```
digits = [0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,5,2,3]
```

if you want to keep with number smaller and equal to 2:

```
new_digits=list(filter(lambda x:x<=2,digits))
```

so:

```
print(new_digits)
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```